# Spring default-lazy-init does not seems to work, i see Pre-instantiating of singletons

Tags: java, spring, lazy-initialization

I am defining default-lazy-init="true" in the spring context file inside beans tag but when I start tomcat, I see my beans are getting instantiated. here is what it shows in log -

org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:555) - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@ac6fb1: defining beans [dataSource,my other beans in app.......

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Post the full stack trace or log. Post your context.

Answer (score 7):

Even if a bean is declared to be lazy initialized, it will still be initialized if another bean depends on it.

I'm going to assume from your log, that the bean in question is `dataSource`. I will also assume you have other beans that depend on `dataSource` (otherwise it wouldn't be very useful). If the context initializes the other beans and finds that, for example, it needs to autowire the `dataSource` bean, it will have to first initialize it.

If you want full lazy initialization, you will have to make every bean in some object graph be lazily initialized.

Comment: Thx for ur reply, I have 100+ other beans (controllers, services, dao) getting initialized at the same time. can you explain a bit more on "make every bean in some object graph be lazily initialized.".

Comment: @amit Say your lazy-init bean is `A`. `A` is an injection dependency for `B`. If you request `B` from the `ApplicationContext`, it will initialize `B` (if it hasn't already), and, because of the dependency, also initialize `A`.

Comment: I looked into interdependency aspect but most of them are not. they are part of different functionality/modules. Any other ideas apart from this ?

Comment: @Amit Unless you give us an example (ideally it would be small and reproducible), we can only guess. My best guess is what I've expressed above.